# How to test a function that deals with setting file ownership without being root

Tags: python, linux, testing

I wrote a function that copies the /etc/skel directory on a linux machine during a "create new user" RPC call. Now, there is quite a few things about this I want to test, for example the files in /etc/skel and the *targets* of symlinks should not have changed permissions afterwards, whereas the copied files including the *actual* symlinks should have a changed owner. Now, i can create my test directory and files using mkdtemp and stuff, but I can't chown those to another user without root privileges. How would you write a test for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an object which does the chmod, and inject a mock when testing. This mock would not really do the chmod, but make it possible to test if it was called with the right parameters.

Comment: Of course... You're right, thats probably the best I can do here. Also, in Python, I don't even need to create a separate class for the chmod as you suggested - I probably can just pass in the function (functions being normal objects and such) and mock that....